# Prefer coding than drop and click

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to create a database by coding in SQL express via VS 2010? I prefer SQL coding than doing drop and click.

Comment: Still people do help him. Make sure you don't upvote them so they know better next time:)

Comment: @Stilgar: Yes, but for how long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to obtain [SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx) is to use [Microsoft's Web Platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). You can easily download this tool which will give you acces to all of the necessary tools to get started with web development.

Using the the mangement studio is easy and has a few new such as SQL 2008 code completion, color coding of tabs, color coding of null columns, etc. You can use the mangaement studio for both 2005 and 2008 databases.

Hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the client tools when you installed the SQL Server, then you have a utility called "SQL Server Management Studio". You can do all your TSQL coding in there.

If you have Visual Studio Team Edition for Database Professionals, you can create a database project and create your DDL and DML structures there.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear: Are you saying you have SQL Server 2008 Express but no Management Studio?  <strike>The 2008 version of Management Studio is not a stand alone installation and can only be installed as part of the SQL Server 2008 Express with Tools or Advanced installations.</strike>

This is now downloadable from here: [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM - Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=56ad557c-03e6-4369-9c1d-e81b33d8026b)